# Getting element shows true instead of float value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am Teacher payslip Controller , while getting net_salary using object shows Boolean value instead of their value.

```
def payslip_report
if params[:teacher_id] and params[:month_year].present?
   @month_and_year =   params[:month_year].gsub(' ','')
   @teacher_data   =   TeacherPayslip.where(:teacher_id => params[:teacher_id])
   @matched_records = @teacher_data.select{|t| t.salary_date.strftime("%B%Y") == @month_and_year}
   #returns an array of TeacherPayslip records with matching month and year
  if @matched_records.blank?
     raise "2" 
     else
     @report = @matched_records.first
     raise @report.net_salary.inspect

  end
end
```

end

While inspecting @report.net_salary shows true . @report contains basic,pf,da,net_salary values. @pf = @report.pf means , I will get pf value. But when try to get net_salary shows Boolean value instead of float value.

raise @report.inspect contains

[image]

Here is TeacherPayslip Model

```
 class TeacherPayslip < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :teacher_id,:salary_date,:hra,:bonus,:pf,:da,
                  :special_allowance,:basic,:net_salary,:month_year

   #associations
   belongs_to :teacher


  #callbacks                
    after_create :net_salary

    def net_salary   
        @teacher_id = self.id
        @da  =  (self.basic * self.da)/100 
        @hra = (self.basic * self.hra)/100 
        @gs  = @da + @hra + self.basic
        @pf =  (@gs * self.pf)/100
        @netsalary = @gs - @pf + self.special_allowance + self.bonus
    @a = TeacherPayslip.find(@teacher_id)
    #raise @a.inspect
    @a.update_attribute('net_salary',@netsalary)
  end
end
```

Comment: can you show us your TeacherPayslip model?

Comment: I have included TeacherPayslip Model in above

Answer (score 0):

You have override net salary method, so it doesn't return column value any more. Method returns the value which has been return by the last command. In this case your net_salary method returns whether it managed to update the model or not. Add `net_salary` to the end and everything should go back to normal.

Few more points here though. `Update_attribute` saves the object, which might come as a surprise to anyone calling it. Also it skips all the validations, which means that:

```
t = TeacherPayslip.new
t.net_salary
```

would save empty object to a db.Use `assign_attributes net_salary: @netsalary' instead.

Also, there is no point of searching for new TeacherPayslip (also it would throw an exception for new records), just use `.self.assign_attributes...` - you can even skip `self`.

Comment: it saves nil value for net_salary.

Comment: Use `update_attributes` with a hash instead of `update_attribute` and enable validation.